# Spark Error Running "stats()": could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Double]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm learning spark/scala after just writing some MapReduce jobs.

I wrote some java beans to help me parse a file in HDFS and I want to use that to help speed up my progress in spark.

I've had success loading my file and creating an array of my java bean objects:

```
val input = sc.textFile("hdfs://host:port/user/test/path/out")
import my.package.Record
val clust_recs = clv_input.map(line => new my.package.Record(line))
clust_recs.map(rec => rec.getPremium()).stats()
```

But the last line creates this error:

`<console>:46: error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Double]`

I've tested that the values in this field are all valid, so I am pretty sure I don't have any null values that could be causing this error.

Here is an example of values:

```
val dblArray = clust_recs.map(rec => rec.getPremium()).filter(!isNaN(_))
dblArray.take(10)
```

OUTPUT:

```
res82: Array[Double] = Array(1250.6, 433.72, 567.07, 219.24, 310.32, 2173.48, 195.0, 697.94, 711.46, 42.718050000000005)
```

I'm at a loss to how to resolve this error and wondering if I should just abandon the concept of using a JavaBean object that I've already created.

Comment: Is `my.package.Record` a case class?

Comment: no, my.package.Record is a Java class (traditional java bean, with getters and setters)

Comment: What's the signature of `Record.getPremium()`?

Comment: What's the Spark version?

Answer (score 0):

You can only expect `stats` operator available on a `RDD[T]` by implicit conversions for `RDD[Double]` or `RDD[T]` where `T` can be converted to `Numeric[T]` (see [the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1883-L1890)):

```
implicit def doubleRDDToDoubleRDDFunctions(rdd: RDD[Double]): DoubleRDDFunctions = {
  new DoubleRDDFunctions(rdd)
}

implicit def numericRDDToDoubleRDDFunctions[T](rdd: RDD[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T])
  : DoubleRDDFunctions = {
  new DoubleRDDFunctions(rdd.map(x => num.toDouble(x)))
}
```

The implicit conversions are also mentioned in the scaladoc of [DoubleRDDFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions):

> Extra functions available on RDDs of Doubles through an implicit conversion.

The point is that the following line does not give you `RDD[Double]`, but *something else*.

```
clust_recs.map(rec => rec.getPremium())
```

That's the reason for the following compilation error:

> error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Double]

The Scala compiler can't find `Numeric[Double]` implicit conversion that is called `num`.

```
implicit def numericRDDToDoubleRDDFunctions[T](rdd: RDD[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T])
  : DoubleRDDFunctions = {
  new DoubleRDDFunctions(rdd.map(x => num.toDouble(x)))
}
```

I can only *guess* that the `Double` is Java's `java.lang.Double` not Scala's `Double` and hence the compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting me in the right direction Jacek, your answer got me searching more about how to convert the java.lang.Double to scala.Double in the map function.

As a new user of scala, I'm struggling to get a handle on the differences with Java, especially implicit conversions.

I found this post very helpful: http://www.scala-archive.org/scala-Double-td1939353.html

and ultimately changed the code to this:

```
clust_recs.map(rec => rec.getPremium().doubleValue()).stats()
```

OUTPUT:

```
res28: org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter = (count: 1000000, mean: 170.636, stdev: 28.13, max: 2180.000000, min: 0.000000)
```